# Face detection using color feature

Tags: matlab, face-detection

I am trying to detect faces in my picture. So I found a code that do this, but depending on my picture-input sometimes it finds the faces and for other pictures it doesn't work.

So I thought it because of the face's color of person that is on the picture. So when I change the thresholds value sometimes it make to work.

My thresholds value:

```
 %Threshold
hlow = 0.0;    hhigh = 0.4;
slow = 0.3;    shigh = 0.8;
vlow = 0.4;    vhigh = 0.9;

Blob_Threshold = 120;
Edge_Threshold = 650;
Edge_Tolerance = 500;
Percentage_Threshold = 35;
Tolerance = 0.25;
```

and it here is my code :

```
   function [Faces_List inx_face] = FaceDetection(img)
  %----------------Initialization----------------------
  Temp_img = img;
  img_height = size(Temp_img,1);   %  tedade satr
 img_width = size(Temp_img,2);      %  tedade sotoona
Temp_img = im2double(Temp_img);
Skin     = zeros(img_height,img_width);

%Threshold
hlow = 0.0;    hhigh = 0.4;
slow = 0.3;    shigh = 0.8;
vlow = 0.4;    vhigh = 0.9;

Blob_Threshold = 120;
Edge_Threshold = 650;
Edge_Tolerance = 500;
Percentage_Threshold = 35;
Tolerance = 0.25;
goldenRatio = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
%----------------Convert Color Space From RGB2HSV----
Temp_img = rgb2hsv(Temp_img);
for i = 1:img_height
    for j = 1:img_width
        H = Temp_img(i,j,1);
        S = Temp_img(i,j,2);
        V = Temp_img(i,j,3);
        bh = H >= hlow && H <= hhigh;
        bs = S >= slow && S <= shigh;
        bv = V >= vlow && V <= vhigh;
        if (bh && bs && bv)
            Skin(i,j) = 1;
        end
    end
end
figure;imshow(Skin);title('Skin Color Detection');
%----------------Initialization----------------------
%Skin_Blob = bwconncomp(Skin,8);
[Skin_Blob,Blob_Number] = bwlabel(Skin);
BlobData = regionprops(Skin_Blob,'all');
%Blob_Number = Skin_Blob.NumObjects;
inx_face = 0;
Faces_List = [];
%----------------Main Face Detection-----------------

for i = 1:Blob_Number
    if (BlobData(i).Area > Blob_Threshold)
        myFace = BlobData(i).Image;
        figure;imshow(myFace);
        %pause(1);
        myHeight = size(myFace,1);%height
        myWidth = size(myFace,2);%width
        b1 = (myHeight/myWidth) >= goldenRatio - Tolerance;
        b2 = (myHeight/myWidth) <= goldenRatio + Tolerance;
        b3 = (myWidth/myHeight) >= goldenRatio - Tolerance;
        b4 = (myWidth/myHeight) <= goldenRatio + Tolerance;
        Percentage_skin = (sum(myFace(:)) / (myHeight * myWidth)) * 100;
        b5 = Percentage_skin > Percentage_Threshold;
        boundingBox = BlobData(i).BoundingBox;
        x1 = fix(boundingBox(1));
        y1 = fix(boundingBox(2));
        x2 = fix(boundingBox(3));
        y2 = fix(boundingBox(4));
        edgeFace = imcrop(img,[x1 y1 x2 y2]);
        imGray = rgb2gray(edgeFace);
        imEdge = edge(imGray,'sobel');
        sumEdge = sum(imEdge(:));
        b6 = sumEdge >= Edge_Threshold - Edge_Tolerance;
        b7 = sumEdge <= Edge_Threshold + Edge_Tolerance;
        if (((b1 && b2) || (b3 && b4)) && b5 && (b6 && b7))
            inx_face = inx_face + 1;
            Faces_List(inx_face).x1 = x1;
            Faces_List(inx_face).y1 = y1;
            Faces_List(inx_face).x2 = x2;
            Faces_List(inx_face).y2 = y2;
        end 
    end %end if
end %for i

end%Function
```

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this.

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: I asked which part of code should be changed to work for all pictures input!!!

Comment: @user3235806: define "work on all pictures input" please: if you want your code to detect ALL faces (i.e, 100% [recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Recall)) then simply returning "there's a face" for ANY picture will give you 100% recall. However, if you also want high [precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Precision) - that is low false rate - you are in a jam. Face detection can be very tricky. See [this recent benchmark](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/) for more details.